# Labeling the curves in the plot with their exact value

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

[image]In the following code we are plotting 10 curves in one plot `if Ju<11:`
How can write on each curve in which the reader find out each line is for which `Ju`.
for example on each line we could see `Ju =1`, another line `Ju=2` and ...

I meanputting label on each line with its exact used value

```
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
for n in np.arange(100,200,100):
    for z in np.arange(3,4):
        ET_list=[]
        uf_list=[]
        for xx in range(1,819):
            for uf in np.linspace(1e-26,1e-20,10):
                Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                lim = Ju - Jl
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    if Ju<11:
                        ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, n, 1, uf)/ET(xx, z, n, 1, 0))
                        uf_list.append(uf)  
                        ax1.plot(uf_list, ET_list)  
                    else:
                        pass

ax1.title.set_text('Fig1')
plt.xlabel('Un')
plt.ylabel('TT')
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

any help please

Comment: Could you had a picture of what you currently plot ?

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand you, you could use `pyplot.text(x,y,s) function` to write your text for each line.

Comment: @YohannL.  I uploaded an image

Comment: Have you tried writing text with `pyplot.text(x,y,s)` ?

Comment: @YohannL. Indeed, no. Because I am not professional in plotting figures in Python. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: No problem! I'll write an answer with that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text(x,y,s)` function from `matplotlib`. Here is the documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html

`text` take 3 main arguments, `x` & `y` which are the coordinates of your text. And `s` which is the string you want to write on your plot. For your it will be something like `"Ju={:d}".format(Ju)`.

You should have something like that

```
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
for n in np.arange(100,200,100):
    for z in np.arange(3,4):
        ET_list=[]
        uf_list=[]
        for xx in range(1,819):
            for uf in np.linspace(1e-26,1e-20,10):
                Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                lim = Ju - Jl
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    if Ju<11:
                        ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, n, 1, uf)/ET(xx, z, n, 1, 0))
                        uf_list.append(uf)  
                        ax1.plot(uf_list, ET_list)
                        x = # Put here a float or int that represent the x coordinates of the text
                        y = # Put here a float or int that represent the y coordinates of the text
                        s = "Ju={:d}".format(Ju)
                        ax1.text(x, y, s)
                    else:
                        pass
ax1.title.set_text('Fig1')
plt.xlabel('Un')
plt.ylabel('TT')
plt.show()
```

Something else you could try is just put it as legend. You can set a legend by setting a label for each line using `label` parameter in `ax.plot()`.
Like this:

```
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
for n in np.arange(100,200,100):
    for z in np.arange(3,4):
        ET_list=[]
        uf_list=[]
        for xx in range(1,819):
            for uf in np.linspace(1e-26,1e-20,10):
                Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                lim = Ju - Jl
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    if Ju<11:
                        ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, n, 1, uf)/ET(xx, z, n, 1, 0))
                        uf_list.append(uf)  
                        ax1.plot(uf_list, ET_list, label="Ju={:d}".format(Ju))
                    else:
                        pass
ax1.title.set_text('Fig1')
# You have to set the legend
ax1.legend(loc="best")
plt.xlabel('Un')
plt.ylabel('TT')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you I definitely did not know nothing about this. And now I get `IndexError: list index out of range` for these values and I try another one `-1` and `-1` the plot is empty.

Comment: @MaY, I edited my post with other coordinates, but it may not work either as I don't know where you want to write the text. You have to try different value for `x` and `y`, just understand that `x` must be inferior to the max of `x` axis and `y` must be inferior to `y` axis too see the text in the plot

Comment: No it doesnt work. I would like to eitr them on the lines. if it is not possible that I do not think so, the second alternative is as a legend

Comment: I can't do way more, you have to find the coordinates on our own as I don't have the data you are using. Indeed, you can set a legend, I edited my post to show you how

Comment: Thank you. I answered your question. You said where you want to put the labels. I said maybe like a legend or on the lines. I ll try to figure out, Thanks

Comment: Yes yes, but to put it on the line, you need the coordinates of the line, so you have to retrieve two coordinates (x & y) from the list you're using to plot. But I can't tell you which one, you have to try some of them to find the best